# Is there a formal logical system which works visually?

Tags: logic

I think visually and I like logic, so I'm interested if there exists a formal system which deduces propositions visually (with directed graphs, maybe?). If so, do such systems play an important role in any area of logic, or are they just a useless curiosity?

Comment: Logical connectors can be represented by Venn diagrams. See for example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_conjunction and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_disjunction

Comment: You might be interested in this paper: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1906.11236.pdf (*First-order proofs without syntax* by Dominic J D Hughes)

Comment: Syntax trees are, after all, trees. So actually we are dealing with graphs all the time, but we chose to use symbols written linearly, because that's way, way more convenient.

Answer (score 1):

It can be argued that logic itself is a strictly formalized domain and each inference step can be traced mechanically with assumed background semantic interpretation of quantifiers and the truth value of all predicates from any metalanguage, a mechanical deductive system like [Fitch system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fitch_notation) or some other [sequent calculus sytems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequent_calculus) (Hilbert, Gentzen) are often the official non visual tools. From computer science POV, it's just formal string manipulation rules of a certain Turing machine (like a game), so hardly there's any visual system required.

However, there's nothing wrong for you to try any graph or intuitive sketching method to help you understand and proceed for logic puzzles. A common useful such method used in advanced logic courses are called [tableaux method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_analytic_tableaux). It'll become extremely helpful for you to prove some advanced theorems in mathematical logic in general.